# django query aggregate function is slow?

Tags: django, sqlite, aggregate, django-queryset

I am working with Django to see how to handle large databases. I use a database with fields name, age, date of birth(dob) and height. The database has about 500000 entries. I have to find the average height of persons of (1) same age and (2) born in same year. The aggregate function in querying table takes about 10s. Is it usual or am I missing something?

For age:

```
age = [i[0] for i in Data.objects.values_list('age').distinct()]
ht = []
for each in age:
    aggr = Data.objects.filter(age=each).aggregate(ag_ht=Avg('height')
    ht.append(aggr)
```

From dob,

```
age = [i[0].year for i in Data.objects.values_list('dob').distinct()]
for each in age:
    aggr = Data.objects.filter(dob__contains=each).aggregate(ag_ht=Avg(‌​'height')
    ht.append(aggr)
```

The year has to be extracted from dob. It is SQLite and I cannot use __year (join).

Comment: and how do you filter in second case?

Comment: I use the same structure of filter. ``for each in age:
    aggr = Data.objects.filter(dob__contains=each).aggregate(ag_ht=Avg('height')
    ht.append(aggr);  ht.append(aggr)``

Comment: i will think for your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

full version with time compare loop and query set version

```
import time
from dd.models import Data
from django.db.models import Avg
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractYear
```

for age

```
start = time.time()
age = [i[0] for i in Data.objects.values_list('age').distinct()]
ht = []

for each in age:
    aggr = Data.objects.filter(age=each).aggregate(ag_ht=Avg('height'))
    ht.append(aggr)

end = time.time()
loop_time = end - start

start = time.time()
qs = Data.objects.values('age').annotate(ag_ht=Avg('height')).order_by('age')
ht_qs = qs.values_list('age', 'ag_ht')
end = time.time()
qs_time = end - start

print loop_time / qs_time
```

for dob year, with easy refactoring your version(add set in the years)

```
start = time.time()
years = set([i[0].year for i in Data.objects.values_list('dob').distinct()])
ht_year_loop = []
for each in years:
    aggr = Data.objects.filter(dob__contains=each).aggregate(ag_ht=Avg('height'))
    ht_year_loop.append((each, aggr.get('ag_ht')))

end = time.time()
loop_time = end - start

start = time.time()
qs = Data.objects.annotate(dob_year=ExtractYear('dob')).values('dob_year').annotate(ag_ht=Avg('height'))
ht_qs = qs.values_list('dob_year', 'ag_ht')
end = time.time()
qs_time = end - start

print loop_time / qs_time
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17337035)

Comment: @BradGilbert why not? if i'm correct this query have to be more fast and give the same values.

Comment: Yes, it does for age. But I was hoping to have a common code for both the age and year cases. There is also a date of birth(dob) field and I want to do the same aggregate by extracting year from dob field. So for that I plan to just modify  ``age = set([i.year for i in Data.objects.values_list('age').distinct()])`` but it is slow. It is SQLite so __year (join) cannot be done.

Comment: can you write inside your question what real you need and may be some one can give full and good answer.

Comment: That was an automated comment generated from a review queue. I do not know anything about the topic, it just looked like it doesn't answer the question. If it were longer and actually explained why it should work I wouldn't have voted to close it.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For these queries to be efficient, you have to [create indexes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/optimization/) on the `age` and `dob` columns.

You will get a small additional speedup by using [covering indexes](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx), i.e., using two-column indexes that also include the `height` column.